# Highcharts.stockChart is not a function

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to make a graph using Hightcharts.js, but get an error

> TypeError: Highcharts.stockChart is not a function.

I install it using npm(package.json)

```
"highcharts": "^5.0.6"
```

Сall

```
var Highcharts = require('highcharts');
```

And use

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        alignTicks: false,
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    title: {
        text: 'AAPL Stock Volume'
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'AAPL Stock Volume',
        data: [],
        dataGrouping: {
            units: [[
                'week', // unit name
                [1] // allowed multiples
            ], [
                'month',
                [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
            ]]
        }
    }];
};
var chart = Highcharts.stockChart(options);
```

Highstock is not a separate module, and belongs to Highcharts, I do not understand what could be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Highstock not a separate module, and belongs to Highcharts . This is not true.

But the reverse is. if you include Highstock then you need not to include Highcharts again.

As per the Highcharts documentations

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/installation

Highcharts is already included in Highstock, so it is not necessary to load both. The highstock.js file is included in the package.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function (data)    {
        // Create the chart
        
        var dataObject = {
            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1,
                inputEnabled: $('#container').width() > 480
            },
            
            title: {
                text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },
            
            series: [{
                name: 'AAPL',
                data: data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
            
            ,
            
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container'
            }
            
        };
        
         var chart = new Highcharts.stockChart(dataObject);   
    });
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/5.0.6/css/highcharts.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/5.0.6/js/highstock.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

npm install `highcharts-angular`, then

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';
```

Comment: Thanks, this is all I needed to do in a React application. I was only importing from 'highcharts', and .highstocks was undefined, but adding /highstock to the import made it available.